# Is it possible to increase the UICollectionViewLayout viewport? (i.e. load +2/-2 cells outside the UICollectionView frame)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a full screen Image gallery working using UICollectionView. It is paged and it all runs ok but there is one thing I don't like.

The cells are reused only when they get in the visible viewport and I get a flickering effect when the new image is assigned (normal for the current behaviour).

How do I specify a viewport that is slightly larger than the current UICollectionView frame so that I load and reuse +1/-1 pages that are outside of view? When they get into view they'll already be initialized and ready to go so the flicker effect will go away.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: This is assumed vertical, adjust for horizontal

You can make the frame larger and then add a contentInset

```
CGFloat offset = 40.0; // or whatever works

CGRect yourFrame = yourCollectionView.bounds;
yourFrame.size.height += offset;
yourCollectionView.bounds = yourFrame;

CGFloat halfOffset = offset / 2.0;
yourFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(halfOffset, 0, halfOffset, 0);
```

You will have to place these according to your code, but here's what we're doing.  We're extending your frame a little bit so that cell reuse happens outside the visible bounds.  By adding the insets to your flow layout, you allow the content to still align properly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is partially correct in that you can achieve what am I saying but is not working quite right for my case. Also I'd put this into workaround/hack category since the frame of the collectionView cannot be trusted once you do this and you have to take into consideration this offset when returning itemSizes and recalculating sectionInsets. I'll mark this as correct since I don't think there is a better solution for now.

Comment: Yea, I definitely agree it's a touch hackier, I just haven't come up with a better solution to the "flicker" problem.  Let me know if you find something better! Feel free to hold off on accepting to see if someone comes up with something better if you'd prefer.